# Using ui.router how to make one controller the child of another?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In html you can make one controller the child of another by writing it in a nested html code:

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
```

But using `ui.router`, you can only specify one state being the child of another, how do you make the controller also inherit from the parent state's controller? For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/parent.html',
                controller  : 'ParentController'
            },

        }
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
        url: '/child',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/child.html',
                controller  : 'ChildController'
            },
        }
    })
```

In this case is `ChildController` inherit from `ParentController` automatically? If not how do I make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `ui-router` [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only):

> **Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only**
>
> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain
>   if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope
>   properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and
>   everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).

So, the answer - it depends. It depends on how you configured/specified your views within you state chain.

Hope it will help.

Comment: so does this mean if one `ui-view` is nested in another `ui-view` then the $scope of their controllers are inherited?